# Can I install GIS Software on RSS (informix server) running 11.7.fc6

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I currently use ArcGIS Server 10.0 and consume data through a db2 database. I recently installed an RSS informix server and was hoping to pull data from this since it is updated real-time versus the nighly update of the db2.

RSS Informix Server Version: 11.7.fc6 OS: AIX 6.1
GIS Server: 10.0

If I stay at Server 10.0, I would have to install ArcSDE (I assume) on the Informix Server. Can SDE be installed on an Informix Server running 11.7.fc6 OS: AIX 6.1?

**
Edit: I see ArcSDE 10 isn't compatible with 11.7.FC6.
But is it possible to install ArcSDE 10.1 on Informix (assuming Informix version is supported by 10.1) while still remaining at 10.0 Server with capability of publishing the Informix data as a service on Server 10.0?
**

If I upgraded to 10.1 Server, the Informix capability is already there without installing SDE, BUT this link shows support for only FC8 and FC4. How would FC6 react or would I need an upgrade to FC8?

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000071000000